# Date Conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert date format in Javascript like

```
(MM-dd-YYYY) to (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

please suggest some standard format for conversion

Comment: Look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: this is pretty common question, you should have shown some effort :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var newDate =  curr_year  + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
var str = "01-17-2021";
var arr = str.split("-");
var dateFormatted= arr[2]+"-"+arr[0]+"-"+arr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link.
http://jsfiddle.net/9C2p8/

```
   var start = new Date('10-10-2013');

   var startDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(start));
   alert(startDate);
```